# kubernetes pod resource cpu on nodes with different cpu cores count

Tags: kubernetes

This is a bit crazy, but we run a kubernetes cluster with 4 nodes (w/ Docker as container engine):

- node01/node02: 8 cores
- node03/node04: 4 cores

I am confusing about exactly what pod resource request cpu give as real cpu for a containerized application.

In my understanding, pods from a deployment that request 1 CPU, will all have the same cpu shares, so this mean a container will run faster on node01/node02 than 03/04 ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What CPU request do you set on the Deployment? But yes, a container typically runs faster if it has more CPU resources or faster CPU available.

Comment: Thanks, added it in the question, let say pods request.cpu = 1

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily:

- If the application is single-threaded, it will run at the same speed no matter how many cores the system it's on has.
- If the application is disk- or database-bound, adding more cores won't make it go faster.
- If other pods (or non-Kubernetes processes) are running on either of the nodes, those share the CPU resource, and a busy 8-core system could in practice be slower than an idle 4-core system.
- If the pod spec has [resource requests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/), it could be prevented from running on the smaller system

  ```yaml
  resources:
     requests:
       cpu: 6 # can't run on the 4-core system
  ```
- If the pod spec has resource limits, that can prevent it from using all of the cores, even if it's scheduled on the larger system

  ```yaml
  resources:
     limits:
       cpu: 3 # even if it's scheduled on the 8-core system
  ```

Comment: Actually , the problem we have is a nodejs application throw OOM exception when pod is running on small node , I  saw (via grafana nodejs metrics) in this case there are less GC runs than on big node , that's why I have concluded that even with same CPU request , pod will have less CPU on small node

Comment: thanks you, so CPU request will be the garuanted CPU, if my pod need more, node could not give more if there is no more shares available ? (that why I see OOM only on small nodes)

Comment: CPU and memory are different resources.  Being able to run more tasks in parallel doesn't necessarily mean you'll use more memory.  Conversely, it's possible the node with fewer cores also has less memory available, and that's why you're hitting OOM issues.  Setting `memory:` requests and limits on your pods is a good practice.